# Array can't be coerced into Float (TypeError) on my Ruby code

Tags: ruby

I am supposed to make variables that convert standard units into metric units. This is an exercise for a lesson on *Learn Ruby the Hard Way*. I'm trying to run the following code in PowerShell. The information inside the code is from the author of the book.

```
name = 'Zed A. Shaw'
age = 35 # not a lie in 2009
height = 74 # inches
weight = 180 # lbs
eyes = 'Blue'
teeth = 'White'
hair = 'Brown'
cm = 2.54
kg_1 = 2
kg_2 = 1/10

puts "Let's talk about #{name}."
puts "He's #{height * cm} inches tall."
puts "He's #{(weight * kg_1) - kg_2} pounds heavy."
puts "Actually that's not too heavy."
puts "He's got #{eyes} and #{hair} hair."
puts "His teeth are usually #{teeth} depending on the coffee."

# this line is tricky, try to get it exactly right
puts "If I add #{age}, #{height * cm}, and #{(weight * kg_1) - kg_2 }"
puts "I get #{age + (height * cm) + [(weight * kg_1) - kg_2]}."
```

It failed when I had to add up everything at the end. When I try to run it in PowerShell, this comes up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
1: from ex5.rb:20:in `<main>'
ex5.rb:20:in `+': Array can't be coerced into Float (TypeError).
```

What is my error, and how do I fix it?

Comment: You cannot use square brackets as math brackets in ruby, square brackets declare an array. `[(weight * kg_1) - kg_2]` → `((weight * kg_1) - kg_2)`

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to this, so I'm glad that I now know this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lays in this line:

```
"I get #{age + (height * cm) + [(weight * kg_1) - kg_2]}."
```

You probably want to see sth like

```
I get 1234.12.
```

You use `[]` brackets to group operations (as you'd do in math class). In Ruby you can only use `()` to group. `[]` is a notation for introducing an array. Try this one:

```
"I get #{age + (height * cm) + ((weight * kg_1) - kg_2)}."
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the error occurs on line:

`puts "I get #{age + (height * cm) + [(weight * kg_1) - kg_2]}."`

The issue here is using `[]` indicates the program should be looking for an array object. By using `[]` here, it is interpreted that you're looking to add an array object to a float object using the `+` method (operators are methods in Ruby). Ruby spits out that error message. It seems what you're looking to do is to:

- add `age` to `(height * cm)` to return a float
- add that float value to the difference between `(weight * kg_1)` and `kg_2`

By replacing:

```
[(weight * kg_1) - kg_2]
```

with

```
((weight * kg_1) - kg_2)`
```

you should receive the intended interpolated value of:

```
I get 582.96
```

Comment: "[U]sing `[]` indicates the program should be looking for an Array object" No, `[]` indicates an array object.